# Java 8 efficient way for adding object to list

Tags: java, list, performance, java-8

Is there a short and efficient way to add object to a list with null check?

```
Book book = new Book();
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(library.getBooks())) {
        library.getBooks().add(book);
} else {
        library.setBooks(Collections.singletonList(book));
}
```

Comment: Why don't initialize the collection inside the library object? Libraries can be empty.

Comment: `CollectionUtils` isn't for java 8

Comment: @Cristiano this is the API, I cannot change it

Comment: @HadiJ I know. I am wondering is there a way to implement it in Java 8 in one row of code. without if else

Comment: You can use `library.getBooks().ifPresentOrElse( library.getBooks().add(book),library.setBooks(Collections.singletonList(book)))` in java 9

Comment: @HadiJ `library.getBooks()` does not return an `Optional`

Comment: right! `Optional.of(library.getBooks()).ifPresentOrElse( library.getBooks().add(book),library.setBooks(Collections.singletonList(book)))`

Comment: @HadiJ Thanks, but the solution doesn't work for Java 8.

Comment: Is this your homework for class? Also making something work in one line of code; I use to do that until debugging was so painful and the code was complicated to read. Since then I break down my functionality into multiple lines for understandably as well as debugging. Using empty list if no list exist is what I would do. I think your question is confusing. why are you needing to check if your books are empty? Should it not matter if their are already books before you add more books?

Comment: @Mr00Anderson my list could be null. I am trying to learn if there is another way in java 8 to preform this check.

Comment: I said empty, not null. I would use a combination of @Eugene and oleg.cherednik answer. Implementing the details in the Library class, so that with one line you can add a book. The Library takes care of the possible null list. Here you can create lazy list instantiation as well as return if the book was added via true or false.

Comment: Your existing code is wrong. At first the list is empty, so you set it to a singletonList. The next time you call this code, it's not empty, so you add another book to it. Then it throws an UnsupportedOperationException because you can't add anything to a singletonList.

Answer (score 4):

I absolutely dislike the fact that your `List` could contain `null`, what is the point of that anyway? Why don't you refactor and return an *empty one* instead. Assuming that you cannot change that (please double check if you can), *don't do it* in a single line, just because it's fancy - it will be very unreadable in this particular case. Besides, I am strongly against these helper methods like `CollectionsUtils` or `StringUtils`, etc - that only make reading the code worse; not saying for all of them though (`guava` has some that I really like and use)

Instead, refactor this one to a simpler, more pleasant to look at method:

```
List<Book> books = library.getBooks();
if(books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
     books.add(book);   
} else {
     library.setBooks(Collections.singletonList(book));    
}
```

How many seconds did it take you to understand this logic? As, for example opposed, to the other answer here (nothing personal, you made an excellent point).

But this still raises some questions for me personally. Why not move this entire logic to the `Library` class? What if you want *later* to add another book to a library? Because you have used `Collections.singletonList` which is immutable, you will not be able to.

Comment: I agree about using other libraries for simple task. Also agree that the list should be empty. I use lazy empty list when the possibility it will be empty to guard against null ptrs and be able to operate on it if empty without making null checks.

Comment: @Mr00Anderson it’s worth noting that since Java 8, `ArrayList` instances created with the default constructor (`new ArrayList<>()`) do not create their backing array until the first element is added. So they are already lazily initialized and implementing another lazy initialization rarely pays off.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I may have forgot that part. I tend to read documentation before performing such things; I did read before commenting, didn't catch the already lazy. I recently left Java to C++ too. Due to a few reasons with the future of Java and current state past Java 10 and my need for performance for my Multiplayer game.

Comment: This still contains the bug from the original code. At first the list is empty, so you set it to a singletonList. The next time you call this code, it's not empty, so you add another book to it. Then it throws an UnsupportedOperationException because you can't add anything to a singletonList.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou *Because you have used Collections.singletonList which is immutable, you will not be able to*... this entire question now that I have read it again - is very misleading